# Eclipse - How to find missing closing brace

Tags: eclipse, groovy, curly-braces

I'm using the Groovy editor in Eclipse.  When I compile/seed my script I sometimes get the below output.

```
839: expecting '}', found '' @ line 839, column 1
```

The line above is the last line in the script which doesn't tell me much.  It just says there is a closing brace missing somewhere in the script.  One way I typically try is to zoom out (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>) as much as possible in my editor (after source code formatting) then I try to look for something that looks oddly indented.  The problem is some blocks are quite long so this is not ideal...

Is there a better approach or easier way to find out where the missing brace is in Eclipse?  Or using another app (i.e. Notepad++, Sublime)?  I would like to avoid using online tools pasting sensitive code.

Answer (score 3):

When you place the cursor after an opening brace, the editor will highlight the closing brace.  And you can jump to the closing brace using Go to Matching Bracket (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).  Similarly, you can place the cursor just before a closing brace to highlight the opening brace and use the same command to jump to it.  Using these aids, you should be able to narrow down where the unpaired opening brace is.

Comment: This is a good way which I use.  Thanks.  It can still be tedious if the file is particularly long.  I'm still wondering if there might be a tool or plugin that can quickly identify the unpaired brace.  I suppose a script to identify this is an option, but it would need to ignore possible "string" braces versus actual code braces etc.

Comment: Another thing you can do in recent eclipse versions is hover the cursor over a closing brace and the opening lines of the block will be displayed.  Still manual, but may give quicker insight vs. Go to Matching Bracket command.